# RxJava not displaying the data

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am new in RXjava. I have impliment it in my project but it is not getting the data and didnot display it. what is the problem here?

My viewModel

```
    public LiveData<Resource<List<Item>>> makeApiCallTopArticles() {

    final MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Item>>> mediumObjectsList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    mediumObjectsList.setValue(Resource.loading());
    APIService apiService = RetroInstant.getRetroMediumClient().create(APIService.class);
    Observable<CnnResponse> observable = apiService.getNewsObjectsList("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss",
            "", "25");

    Observer<CnnResponse> observer = new Observer<CnnResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(CnnResponse value) {
            List<Item> articles = new ArrayList<>();
            assert value != null;
            List<Item> responce = value.getItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < Objects.requireNonNull(responce).size(); i ++) {
                if (!Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(responce.get(i).getEnclosure()).getLink(), null) && !Objects.equals(responce.get(i).getTitle(), "")) {
                    articles.add(responce.get(i));
                }
            }
            mediumObjectsList.postValue(Resource.success(articles));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    };
    observable.subscribe(observer);
    return mediumObjectsList;
}
```

**ViewModel before I added RXjava**

```
public LiveData<Resource<List<Item>>> makeApiCallTopArticles() {

    final MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Item>>> mediumObjectsList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    mediumObjectsList.setValue(Resource.loading());
    APIService apiService = RetroInstant.getRetroMediumClient().create(APIService.class);
    Call<CnnResponse> call = apiService.getNewsObjectsList("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss",
            "", "25");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<CnnResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<CnnResponse> call, @NotNull Response<CnnResponse> response) {
            List<Item> articles = new ArrayList<>();
            assert response.body() != null;
            List<Item> responce = response.body().getItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < Objects.requireNonNull(responce).size(); i ++) {
                if (!Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(responce.get(i).getEnclosure()).getLink(), null) && !Objects.equals(responce.get(i).getTitle(), "")) {
                    articles.add(responce.get(i));
                }
            }
            mediumObjectsList.postValue(Resource.success(articles));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<CnnResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
            mediumObjectsList.setValue(Resource.error(t.getMessage() != null ? t.getMessage() : "Unknown Error"));
        }
    });

    return mediumObjectsList;
}
```

.......................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add logs to: `onNext` and `onError` method. Just to understand that you really receive a response or maybe you have some errors during the request. If you receive an error that can be a reason.

When you're using Rx you should use schedulers to avoid perform long term operation on the main thread. replace you subscription with:

```
observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(observer);
```

Comment: I have added the log and yeah it is shown the error. check out the question I have updated to the oldest code before I used RXjava.

Comment: But what error do you have? Could you share a stacktrace?

Comment: I have added 2 logs as you sayed, one in onNext and on in OnError. And the log OnNext didn't shown in logcat, Just the OnError has shown.

Comment: I mean can you log the error, to understand the reason why it thrown?
  @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
Log.e("error:", "message ", e)
        }

And then share the log.

Comment: Oh ok. Here's the error message "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: When you are using RxJava you should use schedulers to avoid perform long term operations(like network request) on ui(Main) thread. I've edited answer. Because it's hard to attach code snippet to the comment. See the answer's post.

Comment: You are great. It works as expected. Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
observable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(observer);
```